# Pass current array as reference [PHP/Drupal6]

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, pass-by-reference

I have a variable `$doctype` that is an array:

```
$doctype = array(
    'news' => ('news'),
    'documents' => ('documents'),
    'forms' => ('forms'),
    'other' => ('other'),
);
```

which is used as options for another array:

```
$form['doc_type'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Document Type',
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => $doctype,
    '#size' => '30',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $doctype['news'],
```

now I'm trying to pass the current value for another function

I've tried:

```
form($form_state, &$doctype) {
```

but it shows up as a missing argument

I want to pass it through a reference, not as a return (already occupied/don't want to work around it)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Whether an argument is a reference is controlled by the function definition, not the caller.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid unnecessary copying, PHP takes care of that for you. It uses copy-on-write, so it only makes a copy if the function modifies the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `form()` specifies its second argument as a reference, then you shouldn't pass `&$doctype` as a parameter. If the function specifies a parameter as a reference, then all you need to do is pass that variable and it will get passed as a reference.

E.g.

```
<?php
    function form($var1, &$var2) {
        $var2[2] = 5;
    }
    $var2 = array(1,2,3,4);
    form('test', $var2);
    echo $var2[2]; // Echoes '5';
?>
```

However, I'm again assuming that `form()` is built into drupal, in which case as far as I know there's no way of passing `$doctype` as a reference without changing the core code that defines `form()`

Out of curiosity, why do you need to pass it as a reference? Can you clarify "already occupied/don't want to work around it"

Comment: I need it passed so when they upload the file, it's directory is based off of what their document type is. The function is already returning $form, and I cant return more than one value without returning an array or an object, and I've tried both of that so I just said that so people dont suggest to do what I've already tried.

Comment: Also- just referencing the var itself function form($formstate, $doctype) gives me a missing argument error

Comment: Where is `form()` defined? I'm guessing it needs more than two arguments, or you're not defining one of the two. Regardless, given your requirements, you're probably going to need to write your own implementation of `form()` in order to accomplish what you're trying to do.